# SQL Polybase External Table - Dealing with file metadata

Tags: azure-data-lake, external-tables, azure-synapse, polybase

I cannot find any reference for dealing with file metadata when creating an External Table starting from a partitioned source of files. More precisely: I have a set of partitioned parquet files. The partition strategy is in the form:

```
{YEAR}/{MONTH}/{filename}.parquet
```

Now I can create an external table referencing the whole set using the `LOCATION` pointing at the root of the partition and using s recursive strategy.

> LOCATION = 'folder_or_filepath' Specifies the folder or the file path
> and file name for the actual data in Hadoop or Azure blob storage. The
> location starts from the root folder. The root folder is the data
> location specified in the external data source.

In this context, it would be crucial to be able to access partitioning metadata like `{YEAR}`, `{MONTH}` or `{filename}` and store them as columns into the newly created external table for further usages.

By my researches, access file metadata seems to be a missing feature right now. But I'm not sure.
For sure, it is not possible leverages on PARTITION BY functionality as evidenced here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-azure-synapse-analytics/suggestions/19520860-polybase-partitioned-by-functionality-when-creati

Is there some mitigation strategy? I'm about to set up a Data Factory Mapping Dataflow which will do the dirty job. But I'm still unsure about these two options:

1. Reducing the partitioned set into a single file adding metadata columns on each row;
2. Just adding metadata columns on each file and leave the partitioned hierarchy;
3. Bonus: any suggestion?